# ONVIF Device Manager API and Decoder

Tags: c#, c++, ffmpeg, onvif, live555

I'm working on the [source code](https://github.com/aleksandrm8/ONVIF-Device-Manager) of the onvif device manager software and I want to find the Api and decoder it uses.

I first separated the `odm.player` part of the code into another solution and built it separately. the separated part contains these parts from the source code (in order of execution):

```
utils.linq
utils.diagnostics
utils.common
odm.player.lib
odm.player.media
live555
odm.player.net
utils.xml
utils.bootstrapping
odm.player.host
```

Im tring to find the decoder and Api it uses(in the above parts) to decode the media. i need  to find the specific part of the program to contain some information from a decoder.

I know the  source code is using `ffmpeg` and `live555` libraries but I need to find their use and API in the `odm.player` part.

I checked `odm.player.host` because it is the last project and depends on previous ones, but didn't find anything.

what should i do next? is there any official documentation of the API? is there any important keyword related to `ffmpeg` that can I search it in the code?